# Merging two pandas dataframes and sorting them at unique column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I  have two dataframes as shown below and I am trying to merge them. But the issue is I want all the values for columns 'Type' to be under 'Type'. For example if I have 5 rows under 'Type' value "000800.00" in DF1 and 3 rows in DF2. I want all 8 rows to be together under the row that and so on. Is there anyway I can do that.

I have attached pictures with sample data for what both Dataframes look like.

[image: Sample DF1 data]

[image: Sample DF2 data]

Comment: Please put the information here instead of attaching screenshots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
pd.concat(['df1','df2'],sort=False,ignore_index0True)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because there are blank cells under "Type" column.

Comment: please copy and paste your dataframe. Y need it to help you

Comment: Also try my new_solution with pd.concat